# Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuex

auth.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui';

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBfEKjNqtQRdeRxd1ocNwAQjPMo80MUn70",
  authDomain: "qrpay-23f88.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://qrpay-23f88.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "qrpay-23f88",
  storageBucket: "qrpay-23f88.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "651606142877"
};

const auth = {
  context: null,
  uiConfig: null,
  ui: null,

  init(context) {
    this.context = context;

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: 'dashboard',
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ]
    }
    this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.context.$store.dispatch('user/setCurrentUser')

      let requireAuth = this.context.$route.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)
      let guestOnly = this.context.$route.matched.some(record => record.meta.guestOnly)

      if(requireAuth && !user) this.context.$router.push('auth')
      else if (guestOnly && user) this.context.$router.push('dashboard')
    });
  },
  authForm(container) {
    this.ui.start(container, this.uiConfig);
  },
  user() {
    return this.context ? firebase.auth().currentUser : null;
  },
  logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
}

export default auth;
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import App from '@/App'

import {router} from '@/router'
import {store} from '@/store'
import auth from '@/auth'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  beforeCreate () {
    auth.init(this)
  },
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Here i follow this tutorial https://michaljurkowski.medium.com/how-to-make-basic-authentication-in-vue-js-using-google-firebase-e3ec7dad274.

but i get a error Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default.how to solve this?

Comment: Try doing `export { auth }` instead of `export default auth`